# DataTables removes last columns even if viewport is wide enough

Tags: jquery, datatables

In the example below, you can see **Col D** is removed/hidden by DataTables even though the table is wide enough to accommodate it. Is there an option to 
prevent this without individually settting the priority of each columns?

**HTML**

```
<table class="myDataTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Col A</th>
            <th>Col B</th>
            <th>Col C</th>
            <th>Col D</th>              
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>         
        <tr>
          <td>Foo 1</td>
          <td>Foo 2</td>
          <td>Foo 3</td>
          <td>Foo 4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>        
</table>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('.myDataTable').DataTable({
            responsive: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/erJVMY

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.myDataTable').DataTable({
    responsive: false
});
```

This will fix the issue.

Comment: Sorry but I need that option to be `true`

Comment: If responsive is set true, then it will automatically hide columns just to fit in the available space. Another option is to set `responsive: false` and add your own custom styles to make table responsive.

Comment: The issue is, there is significantly available space, so it appears to be a bug. In fact, if you add another column (e.g., Col E)  it will show Col D and hide Col E or whatever is the last column.

Comment: Can you just give `width:100%` to table tag and tell me if it is done.

Comment: That appears to work but only if set inline (e.g., `<table style="width:100%"`), placing it externally CSS won't work